# Wordpress. html code disappears after adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need to add html code to the page . Adding tab through the "text" on page editing records ( ie where html-code of the page) .

But content with my html- code is not fully displayed . What it can be connected and what am I doing wrong ?

Interestingly, when you view the source code for my updated page is seen. After I change my contribution in the editor with the " text " to " visually " disappears code in html page and view the code disappears just after the upgrade. Just disappear all tags

.
My html code:

```
<div class="colorScheme">
<div class="img-color-box afina"><img alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/afina/1003.jpg" /></div>
<div class="link-box afina">

<li class="link-color ral1003" name="abc" href="#" data-color="1003"></li>
<li class="link-color ral1014" name="abc" href="#" data-color="1014"></li>
<li class="link-color ral3005" name="abc" href="#" data-color="3005"></li>
<li class="link-color ral3009" name="abc" href="#" data-color="3009"></li>
<li class="link-color ral3011" name="abc" href="#" data-color="3011"></li>
<li class="link-color ral5005" name="abc" href="#" data-color="5005"></li>
<li class="link-color ral6002" name="abc" href="#" data-color="6002"></li>
<li class="link-color ral6005" name="abc" href="#" data-color="6005"></li>
<li class="link-color ral6020" name="abc" href="#" data-color="6020"></li>
<li class="link-color ral7004" name="abc" href="#" data-color="7004"></li>
<li class="link-color ral7024" name="abc" href="#" data-color="7024"></li>
<li class="link-color ral8004" name="abc" href="#" data-color="8004"></li>
<li class="link-color ral8017" name="abc" href="#" data-color="8017"></li>
<li class="link-color ral8019" name="abc" href="#" data-color="8019"></li>
<li class="link-color ral9003" name="abc" href="#" data-color="9003"></li>
<li class="link-color ral9006" name="abc" href="#" data-color="9006"></li>
</div>
</div>
```

(someone recomended me add atribute "name" with some value, but its doesnt work)

My CSS:

```
.colorScheme {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
.link-box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.link-color {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.ral1003 {
    background: rgb(245,221,27);
}
.ral1014 {
    background: rgb(222,221,164);
}
.ral3005 {
    background: rgb(80,2,0);
}
.ral3009 {
    background: rgb(144,2,0);
}
.ral3011 {
    background: rgb(222,0,0);
}
.ral5005 {
    background: rgb(19,108,250);
}
.ral6002 {
    background: rgb(2,177,14);
}
.ral6005 {
    background: rgb(0,124,0);
}
.ral6020 {
    background: rgb(23,92,0);
}
.ral7004 {
    background: rgb(204,204,204);
}
.ral7024 {
    background: rgb(104,129,134);
}
.ral8004 {
    background: rgb(189,90,0);
}
.ral8017 {
    background: rgb(82,60,37);
}
.ral8019 {
    background: rgb(58,57,55);
}
.ral9003 {
    background: rgb(228,232,233);
}
.ral9006 {
    background: rgb(211,221,222);
}
```

I guess that WP just removes my tags because they have no content or may be css just can not see them , but I still do not know how to solve this problem. Tell me, please .

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `ul` around all those `li's`. WordPress is probs stripping it out because its invalid

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added <ul> in my code, but without success. Anyway the code is erased.